# Do I need to "side" with the companions to unlock skyforge new smithing stuff?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Spoiler alert.

I just want to be able to forge the Nord stuff.
Do I need to become a werewolf and side with these guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: Yes. In order to unlock Nord and Ancient Nord gear at the [Skyforge](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Skyforge_(Skyrim)#Skyforge_smithing), you need to complete the Companions quest line

> The Skyforge can be used as a regular forge with the additional option of forging Nord Hero Weapons and Ancient Nord Armor **after completing The Companions' questline**
>
> <sub>(emphasis my own)</sub>